# How to check if a lable location is overlapping with button location?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a label and a button in the windows form and i am moving the location of the label to the left based on the label text size using the following code:

```
lblsize = lblVal.Text.Length;
if (lblsize > 5)
{
    lblIncrement = (lblsize - 5) * 7;
    lblVal.Location = new Point(lblVal.Location.X , lblVal.Location.Y);
    btn.Location = new Point(btn.Location.X, btn.Location.Y);
    if (lblVal.Bounds.IntersectsWith(btn.Bounds))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        lblVal.Location = new Point(lblVal.Location.X - lblIncrement, lblVal.Location.Y);
    }

}
```

But when i am checking if the label bounds is intersecting with the button bounds it is not working.

Comment: Why are you moving the label? Is it some kind of text alignment thing? You can force a size for a label and set the text alignment.

Comment: @john Yes the text is bigger than the label size so i am moving the label only if the text size is greator than label size. I want to stop moving if it intersects with the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can print the location of both controls to the console to check if the intersection exists or not. If yes and you still getting false for intersection check, then they are on **different panels**.

BTW, those line are doing nothing: (except of generating new objects...)

```
blVal.Location = new Point(lblVal.Location.X , lblVal.Location.Y);
btn.Location = new Point(btn.Location.X, btn.Location.Y);
```